# Is this probability distribution mathematically possible?

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$. Let $\mathbb Q_{[0, 1]} = \{R_1,R_2,R_3...\}$, where $R_n$ denotes individual rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Let $\mathbb R_{[0,1]}-\mathbb Q_{[0,1]}$ denote the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$. Is it possible to assign probabilities such that $P(R_n)=\frac {1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $\forall X (X\in \mathbb R_{[0,1]}-\mathbb Q_{[0,1]}), P(X)=0$? Does this probability assignment violate any axioms?

Comment: Sort of a nitpick, but no need for the notation $A_B$ if all you mean is $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the (discrete) distribution $P_1$, defined on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1] = \{R_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ by 
$$
P(R_n) = \frac{1}{2^{n}}
$$
This is well-defined.
Let further $P_2$ denote the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Then the mixture
$$
P = \frac{1}{2} P_1+\frac{1}{2}P_2
$$
satisfies what you want.